# What's the meaning of ffmpeg's fps options?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to catch some snapshots from a video. So I found this code in their official page:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 img%03d.jpg
```

but, I can not find any documentation about options and they never explain it.

So if you know some reference or documentations about ffmpeg options, please share.

The main question of this post is what `image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60` means.
I cannot understand why they just write like `fps=1/60`. 
And `image2` is some kind of option or what?

What's the difference to the following?

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -ss 00:00:01 -r 1/60 image%03d.png
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) on the FFmpeg homepage.

The [`fps` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) has multiple options, one being `fps`. So, to declare that option, you have to call:

```
-vf fps=fps=1/60
     ↑   ↑   ↑
     |   |   |
     |   |   |__ value
     |   |______ option
     |__________ filter
```

You could also write `-vf fps="fps=1/60"`, of course.

So, when you use `1/60` that means 1/60 frames per second, or 1 frame per 60 seconds. In any case the difference between this and `-r 1/60` is that a filter is applied before any `-r` option. Both commands you gave should work in theory, however the `-r` one creates too many output frames for me (but [I'm not the first one to notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955316)). Stick with the `fps` filter.

---

Note that there is another [filter called `framerate`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#framerate), which is similar to `fps`, but not the same. Instead of duplicating or dropping frames to achieve the target framerate, it will interpolate frames, i.e. merging adjacent frames to create new images.

---

If you dissect the command you will find that `image2` is the option value of `-f`. This specifies the output format. In general, you can use it in `ffmpeg` like this:

```
ffmpeg -f input-format -i input-file -f output-format output-file
```

In your example, we told `ffmpeg` to use [the `image2` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-2), which allows you to output single image files from video, by specifying a pattern like `%02d` for the output name.

The `-f image2` is superfluous here as the muxer should be chosen automatically when you use an image output format.

The `image2` demuxer also has a `framerate` option that allows you to specify the assumed input file framerate. For example, if you have a slideshow that consists of one picture every second, use `-framerate 1` as an input option. See [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) for some examples.

Comment: Thank you so much:D i don't even know there's filter option!

Comment: `-vf` and `-filter:v` mean the same, but it's more apparent that it's a filter with the `-filter` one, of course. I had a talk with someone on  the FFmpeg mailing list and they also said that `-r` shouldn't be used to set the frame rate for the output. `-filter:v fps` is preferred.

Comment: @slhck As a trivial and mostly unrelated side note, `ffplay` doesn't seem to like `-filter:v` compared to `-vf` (but it has been a while since I've tried due to travel).