# FFmpeg blend video frames - seems to be doing excess work?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, blend

I'm blending every 16 frames down to 1 to drastically shorten a timelapse video.

However, it runs very slowly. Is it blending every frame with the 15 following frames, then dropping 15/16 of the frames?  That would mean it is doing 16x as much work as it needs to.

If so, is there a better (faster) way to blend frames that doesn't do redundant work?

```
-vf "tmix=frames=16:weights='1',select='not(mod(n\,16))',setpts=0.0625*PTS"
```

Comment: How about just increasing the frame rate times 16? Seems that would be the simplest way to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Increasing the frame rate does display the file faster, but then when I post it anywhere that only supports up to 60fps, they drop the extra frames.  I'd like to blend them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are doing too much work to blend frames; that should just be a natural part of converting and not a big/complex param in a command.

I mean think about taking an image and scaling it down; you don’t have to do a custom algorithm to change the pixels when going from 10 inches to — let’s say — 1 inch in size. It’s just an inherent part of the process.

Looking at [this answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1583870/167207) I believe there is a simpler way to approach this by using the [`fps`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1) video filter in FFmpeg. I believe — for your purposes — the command can be simplified to be just something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v fps=fps=1/16 output.mp4
```

The key part is the `-filter:v fps=fps=1/16` option.

Look at [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/584823/167207) for another explanation on how the `fps` filter works.

---

And here are some other ideas based on the advice in [this answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182938/117259)…

This one uses the FFmpeg [`minterpolate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#minterpolate) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf minterpolate=fps=1/16 output.mp4
```

And this one uses the FFmpeg [`framerate`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -vf framerate=fps=1/16 output.mp4
```